# Is there a more 'Angular' way to implement this (communication between two elements)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a customized directive, which will add an asterisk for the `required` input field. Here is my link function, explained with comments:

```
// The DOM looks like this:
// <label id="label-1" for="example-1">Name:</label>
// <input id="example-1" type="text" acc-required>

function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // element would be input node
    // I included jQuery, so that I can use the selector as following.
    var label = $("label[for='" + element.attr('id') + "']");
    if (label) {
        // @ add asterisk to the label of a required input field
        var abbrElement = angular.element('<abbr title="required" class="required-marker"">*</abbr>');
        label.append(compile(abbrElement)(scope));
    }
}
```

Is it a smell to select label based on the id attribute for input?

Comment: The `for` attribute is not required, and if absent, a label is attached to the first labelable descendant. For example, `<label>Name: <input ...></label>` is valid but won't work with your code! See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) for the specifics. I think your directive is fine if it supports both cases!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid DOM traversal, and hence the use of ids and `for` and jQuery, I suggest putting the directive on the label rather than the input:

```
<label acc-required>Name:</label>
```

```
app.directive('accRequired', function() {
   return {
      compile: function(element) {
         element.append('<abbr title="required" class="required-marker"">*</abbr>');
      }
   }
});
```

---

**Update:**  Using @stevuu's HTML, here is one way to check for a label without ids, while keeping the directive on the form element:

```
<label>Name1:
    <input type="text" acc-required>
</label>
```

```
app.directive('accRequired', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var label = element.parent();
        if(label) {
            element.before('<abbr title="required" class="required-marker">*</abbr>');
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/CQZp4/)</kbd>

Note that $compile is not required, since the HTML we are adding does not contain any directives.

I did need to include jQuery for this... jqLite doesn't implement before().

Comment: @XiaoPeng, I see your point, but if the directive is only adding the asterisk and class to the label, then maybe it would semantically be better on the label.  Maybe change the directive name to something like `mark-as-required`.  If you still prefer to put it on the element, see my updated answer.